# Does $|f(x,y)| \leq g_x(y)$ pointwise imply $\sup_x |f(x,y)| \leq g(y)$ if $f$ is smooth and compactly supported in $x$?

Tags: continuity, upper-lower-bounds, smooth-functions

Consider a function $f(x,y)$ smooth in both variables and $f(x,y) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb R\backslash K$ for some compact set $K$.

I know that for each $x$, there is a constant $M_x$ such that $|f(x,y)| \leq M_x g(y)$, where $g$ is a known function. *However, I do not know how $M_x$ depends on $x$, so I do not know that $\sup_x M_x < \infty$ a priori*.
**Question:** Does the compact support of $f(x,y)$ in $x$ imply
$$
  \sup_x |f(x,y)| \leq \sup_x M_x g(y)  \equiv M g(y)?
$$
It would be sufficient if, for example, the $M_x$ is a continuous and compactly supported function in $x$. It is certainly compactly supported, as we have $|f(x,y)| = 0$ for $x \not \in K$. But continuity is not clear to me.

Unfortunately, I do not have much else to offer regarding my own attempts.

**Edit:**
For non-continuous functions, pointwise bounds do not imply uniform bounds. Just because $|f(x)| \leq M_x$ for all $x \in K$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \not \in K$, we do not know that $\sup_x |f(x)| < \infty$ (for example $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $0<x<1$ and 0 otherwise).

What I have more in the above case is that $\sup_x |f(x,y)| < \infty$ for $y$ fixed. But I do not see how to deduce that $\sup_x g_x(y) < \infty$ from this.

How would I approach this problem? Do I need more than the stated properties?

**Idea for a proof:**
I could consider instead the equivalent inequality
$$
  \frac{|f(x,y)|}{g(y)} \leq M_x.
$$
Now, the right-hand side is independent of $y$ and we find
$$
  \sup_y \frac{|f(x,y)|}{g(y)} \leq M_x.
$$
Further, the left-hand side is still smooth and compactly supported (**is this actually preserved under supremum norm?**) in $x$, so its supremum exists
$$
  \sup_x \sup_y \frac{|f(x,y)|}{g(y)} \equiv M < \infty.
$$
If it holds for the supremum, it is true for all $x,y$, and so
$$
  |f(x,y)| \leq M g(y).
$$

Comment: You can always take supremum in an inequality. No conditions are needed, not even finiteness of the suprema.

Comment: Same comment as below for clarification:  I do not know the x-dependence of $g_x(y)$. I only know that for each $x$, there is a function $g_x$ (thats what I mean by pointwise estimate). So $\sup_xg_x(y)$ might be infinite. I am looking for a way to show that it is finite, using that $f(x,y)$ is smooth and compactly supp in $x$.

Comment: Then what *is* $g$? At this point it could be literally anything bounding $f$ from above, so we can't exactly conclude anything about whether its uniformly bounded or not

Comment: @Lorago Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I actually know that $g_x(y) = M_x g(y)$ where $g$ is a known function and $M_x$ is some constant for each $x$. I added an idea for a proof, but I'm not sure if it works out.

Comment: The compact support is not necessarily preserved when you take the supremum. As a counterexample, suppose you have the functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1,& y\in[-\lvert x\rvert,\lvert x\rvert],\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$Then, for each fixed $x$, the mapping $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is compactly supported,  but $h(x):=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)$ has $\mathbb{R}$ as its support

Comment: @Lorago Note that the support $K$ of $f$ in $x$ is not dependend on $y$. So th counter example does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any $(x,y)$ you have that

$$\lvert f(x,y)\rvert\leq g_x(y)\leq\sup_\xi g_\xi(y),$$

and so $\sup_\xi g_\xi(y)$ is an upper bound for $\lvert f(x,y)\rvert$ (with only $y$ fixed). As the supremum is the smallest upper bound, we thus get that

$$\sup_x\lvert f(x,y)\rvert\leq\sup_x g_x(y)$$

for all $y$. Notice that there is nothing specific about $f$ and $g$ at play here, and so the same proof can be used to show that you can always take supremums in inequalities.

Comment: It seems I didn't express myself clearly. I do not know the x-dependence of $g_x(y)$. I only know that for each $x$, there is a function $g_x$ (thats what I mean by pointwise estimate). So $\sup_x g_x(y)$ might be infinite. I am looking for a way to show that it is finite, using that $f(x,y)$ is smooth and compactly supp in $x$.